# Asp.Net-Core read in js model values on click

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this code in my Asp.Net-Web App with Razor Pages and I am trying to read the inputs in js only when the Submit button is clicked.

In my Razor Page

```
<form method="post">
 <input asp-for="Value1" id="value1" />
 <input asp-for="Value2" id="value2" />
 <button type="submit" value="Search" id="clickme">Search</button>
</form>
```

And in my js I read them:

```
<script>
  var val1 = @Model.Value1;
  var val2 = @Model.Value2;
</script>
```

But the problem is that with this code the values are being read when the app starts, and I need them to be read only after the submit button is clicked. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `@Model.PropertyName`,it would always render the value when app starts,the correct way is to use js to get the value.

Here is a working demo like below:

```
<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="Value1" id="value1" />
    <input asp-for="Value2" id="value2" />
    
    <button type="submit" value="Search" id="clickme" onclick="Search()">Search</button>
</form>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        function Search() {
        var val1 = $('#value1').val();
        var val2 = $('#value2').val();
        //do your stuff....
        }
    </script>
}
```

Not sure what is your scenario,if you just want to pass the two inputs value to the backend,even no need use js.Just keep the property name and the input name be the same.And in the razor pages,it has `BindProperty` attribute to bind the data:

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="Value1" id="value1" />
    <input asp-for="Value2" id="value2" />

    <button type="submit" value="Search" id="clickme">Search</button>
</form>
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public string Value2 { get; set; }       

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
    {                   
        return Page();
    }
    public void OnPost() 
    { 
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Or just add the parameter like below:

```
public void OnPost(string Value1,string Value2) 
{ 
    //do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `javascript` code instead of `razor syntax`. To get value of `@Model.Value1` use `document.getElementById` like below.

```
var val1 = document.getElementById('Value1').value;
var val2 = document.getElementById('Value2').value;
```

---

- Your `clickme` button do not have `onclick` `attribute` so I guess you might be binding click event from javascript or jquery code using `document.getElementById("clickme").onclick = function() {...};` or `$('#clickme').click(function() {...});`. Inside that function you should be using `var val1 = document.getElementById('Value1').value` to get `latest` value.

---

**Note** when you use `razor syntax` like `var val1 = @Model.Value1;` then it will be parsed and send to your browser with corresponding `html` or `text`. So if you try and inspect the `html` from browser console & view rendered source your `script` block would be like below. *(Let's assume that your @Model.Value1 = 10 & @Model.Value2 = "abc")*.

```
<script>
  var val1 = 10;
  var val2 = abc; //<-- here it will not have "", so it will treated abc as an object.
  // Also it will throw an error here because there might not be any object abc.
  // If you want it to be print as string then you should be wrap @Model.Value2 with "" or '' like below.
  // var val2 = "@Model.Value2"; which will convert to var val2 = "abc";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understood you need **the values to be read only after Submit click**. You need to add a click event to the Submit button:

```
 <button type="submit" value="Search" id="clickme" onclick="initializeValues()">Search</button>
```

The function initializeValues() will be executed only when Submit button is clicked:

```js
<script>
var val1 ; 
var val2 ;
function initializeValues()
{
 val1 = @Model.Value1;
 val2 = @Model.Value2;
}
</script>
```